# omnet simulation of token bucket

Tags: omnet++

am developing a simulation model on the omnet++..Basically my work is to develop something related to LTE, but first I need to develop a simple model which takes the packet from a source and store it in a queue for sometime and deliver it to sink...

I have developed this model and its working fine for me....

Now I need to place tokenbucket meter in between the queue and the sink...to handle the burst and send back rejected packet from the token meter back to the queue..something like second attached image..I have taken this tokenbucketmeter from the simuLTE package of OMNET...

When I simulate this, it is showing error like

```
Quote: cannot cast (queueing::Job *)net.tokenBucketMeter.job-1 to type 'cPacket *'
```

Am not getting where exactly the problem is, may be the source am using is creating the jobs, and tokenbucket meter accepts only the packets..If it is so then what type of the source should I use??

Will you please clarify this?? Will be very thankful

Answer (score 0):

I am using OMNeT++ in a project at the moment too.  Learning to use OMNeT++ having only touched some C99 before can be a bit frustrating.

From checking the demo projects you are using as a base for your project - it looks like `Job` and `cPacket` do not share any useful types other than `cObject` so I would not try to cast like this.

Have a look at `PassiveQueue.cc` in the `/queueinglib` project handles Jobs - everything is passed around as a `cMessage` and cast using the built in cast:

```
cMessage msg (comes in from method signature)

Job *job = check_and_cast<Job *>(msg);
```

cPackets, which you want to use, are a child of cMessage in the inheritance hierarchy shown in this link:

http://www.omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/api/index.html

I am not using `cPackets` myself, but it seems likely, given how protocols work,  that you would be able to translate a message into one or more packets.

Comment: Ya that's correct..cPacket is derived class of cMessage..But there are many components available in the omnet which work only with the cPacktes..Hence am facing difficulty in type casting from cMessage to cPacket..When we try to connect such components with a source generating cMessage they generate typecasr error..Have to tried trypecasting from cMessage to cPacket..or else do you know any source which can produce cPackets??

Comment: Searching in the demo projects indicate that the same library cast as above exists for the cast you need:

`cPacket *myPacket = check_and_cast<cPacket *>(msg);`

_See example: samples\routing\node\L2Queue.cc Line:82_

Do you have any example code you could post in your question?